# Newbie question about programming Altera Cyclone II in Quartus II

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, cyclone

I bought a cheap board with Altera Cyclone II from ebay and want to start experimenting.

I created a simple program, after some research I managed to compile it and after flashing to the board the programming tool said it is 100% complete.

However the behaviour of the board has not changed since the time I first plugged the power supply in(three onboard LEDs are blinking).

It looks like the program has not been loaded to the board.

I don't know what I did wrong.

Any ideas? I am completely new to FPGAs. Thank you

Comment: *"I bought a cheap board with Altera Cyclone II from ebay"* Not a great way to start a question about something that does not work.... What did you program, and what did you expect to see? What do you think is causing the LEDS to blink at the moment?

Comment: I think that the LEDs are blinking because the original program is still in the FPGA, but maybe I am not right. This is my first experience with FPGA. By the way it is this module: https://www.ebay.ca/itm/263616297793

Comment: We will need more details to help you out :D. Can you edit your post with the FPGA used, the program used, the code used,.. And any steps you did so that we can spot the possible mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the configuration stream is written into fpga sram, and it won't live across the power cycle. If you want that configuration be "permanent", write it into on-board configuration flash chip.

Did you check with this short introduction: http://laurie.tech/start-fpga/ ?

Comment: This introduction worked. Thank you very much, Vlad!